# how to convert an adjacency matrix into a list of links

Tags: python, json, list

How to convert python list into JSON format with just using the basic tools and utilities and include the specific "name", "group", "source", "target" key names etc? Is it basically alot of string concatenations to construct that format?

The list index represent connectivity, for example index 0 in the list connects to index 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 1 connects to 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

List:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 4, 7, 9], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Into something like this JSON format?

```
    {"nodes":
[
{"name":"Zone1","group":0},
{"name":"Zone2","group":1},
{"name":"Zone3","group":2},
{"name":"Zone4","group":3},
{"name":"Zone5","group":4},
{"name":"Zone6","group":5},
{"name":"Zone7","group":6},
{"name":"Zone8","group":7},
{"name":"Zone9","group":8},
{"name":"Zone10","group":9}
],
"links":[
{"source":0,"target":1},
{"source":0,"target":3},
{"source":0,"target":4},
{"source":0,"target":5},
{"source":0,"target":6},
{"source":0,"target":7},
{"source":0,"target":8},
{"source":0,"target":9},
{"source":1,"target":0},
{"source":1,"target":2},
{"source":1,"target":3},
{"source":1,"target":4},
{"source":1,"target":5},
{"source":1,"target":6},
{"source":1,"target":7},
{"source":1,"target":8},
{"source":1,"target":9},
{"source":2,"target":1},
{"source":2,"target":3},
{"source":2,"target":4},
{"source":2,"target":7},
{"source":2,"target":9},
{"source":3,"target":0},
{"source":3,"target":1},
{"source":3,"target":2},
{"source":3,"target":4},
{"source":3,"target":5},
{"source":3,"target":6},
{"source":3,"target":7},
{"source":3,"target":9},
{"source":4,"target":0},
{"source":4,"target":1},
{"source":4,"target":2},
{"source":4,"target":3},
{"source":4,"target":6},
{"source":4,"target":7},
{"source":4,"target":8},
{"source":5,"target":0},
{"source":5,"target":1},
{"source":5,"target":3},
{"source":5,"target":6},
{"source":5,"target":7},
{"source":5,"target":8},
{"source":5,"target":9},
{"source":6,"target":0},
{"source":6,"target":1},
{"source":6,"target":3},
{"source":6,"target":4},
{"source":6,"target":5},
{"source":6,"target":7},
{"source":6,"target":8},
{"source":6,"target":9},
{"source":7,"target":0},
{"source":7,"target":1},
{"source":7,"target":2},
{"source":7,"target":3},
{"source":7,"target":4},
{"source":7,"target":5},
{"source":7,"target":6},
{"source":7,"target":8},
{"source":7,"target":9},
{"source":8,"target":0},
{"source":8,"target":1},
{"source":8,"target":4},
{"source":8,"target":5},
{"source":8,"target":6},
{"source":8,"target":7},
{"source":8,"target":9},
{"source":9,"target":0},
{"source":9,"target":1},
{"source":9,"target":2},
{"source":9,"target":3},
{"source":9,"target":5},
{"source":9,"target":6},
{"source":9,"target":7},
{"source":9,"target":8}
]}
```

Comment: The first part of the format with the Zones is trivial and should not be included in the question. The part about the source-target Links requires an if statement in a for loop. Your actual question should be "how to convert an adjacency matrix into a list of links"; JSON has nothing to do with this except for the fact that you are outputting in JSON. If you are only having trouble outputting in JSON, then just use the python `json` module, as a Google search will mention.

Comment: i included that portion because sometimes people will ask me to include the purpose or the goal that i'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from inputs and outputs, here is probably what you want.

```
import json
def convert(adj_lst):
    links = []
    for i,adj in enumerate(adj_lst):
        links.extend( [{'source':i,'target':n} for n in adj] )
    nodes = [{"name":"Zone%d" % i, "group":i} for i in xrange(len(adj_lst))]
    return {"nodes":nodes, "links":links}

adj_list = [[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 4, 7, 9], [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
print json.dumps(convert(adj_list), indent=2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
import json
myjson = json.dumps(mylst)
```

Answer (score 1):

using the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module you should easily be able to encode the list.

As David suggested

`json.dumps` and

`json.loads` to turn from json to python.  Python provides excellent documentation and typing in an unrefined search like 'python json' into google provides appropriate link as first search result